# Grayed out option in popupmenu

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm building an Eclipse plugin. When I right click on items in a table a popup menu with selections pops up. I want a certain selection to be grayed out if more than one items are selected. I have tried using enablesFor="1" in the action tag in my plugin.xml file.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
     <objectContribution         
            id="se.myproject.xxxxxx.ui.ReplaceItemAsReference"
            objectClass="se.xxxxx.xxxx.core.xxxxx.EntityItem">
         <action
               class="se.myproject.xxxxxx.ui.views.ReferenceAction"
               enablesFor="1"
               id="se.myproject.xxxxxx.ui.views.ReplaceItemAsReference"
               label="Do stuff"
               menubarPath="additions-ext">
         </action>       
     </objectContribution>      
</extension>
```

But it's not graying out the selection. I wonder if I have to do some additional coding to achieve this?

[I want the result to look like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hikOu.jpg)

Comment: I assume this is the (deprecated) `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point. 'enablesFor="1"' does work for this. The 'class' value should be a fully qualified class name (so including the package) possibly that is upsetting it.

Comment: Thanks! You assume right.  It is org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus I'm using. I changed 'class' to the fully qualified class name but it's still not working.

Comment: Show us the whole extension point rather than just the 'action'

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious wrong with this. Is the `ReferenceAction` class doing anything to change the enablement in the `selectionChanged` method?

Comment: No I'm not using that method at all. I wonder if it has anything to do with 'objectContribution'. I have another extension point where I'm using 'viewerContribution' and it works there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this may be an Eclipse bug. The 'Restore from Local History' popup menu item is declared in a similar way and also stays enabled for multiple selection.

Other menu items declared using '1' for `enablesFor` do work, the difference seems to be that they use the `<menu>` element to put the menu item in a sub-menu.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I would have spent a lot of time on this one otherwise. I can let this one go for now. Cheers!